# Present a view controller from a container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I had built a `UIViewController` with a container a view that embeds another UIViewController(I will call it subViewController). 
I want the subViewController to present anther instance of it self within its container view canvas (not for all screen).

I tried this using `prepareForSegue` method 
with this method

```
-(void)showFurtherReadingDetails
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowArticleDetails" sender:self];
}
```

**Note** : the `showFurtherReadingDetails` method is a delegate method for subVC over, initialized in the supperVC .
but I faced this issue:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'There are unexpected
>   subviews in the container view. Perhaps the embed segue has already
>   fired once or a subview was added programmatically?'.

Please see The attached image [image]

Comment: How do you present "another instance of it"? Please provide your code.

Comment: I had updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UIViewController is not embedded with UINavigationController then you can not perform Push.

What you have to do is, embed-in navigation controller with your subVC and then  push new view-controller from subVC and it will be in container view and will not take the full screen.

For your convenience, I attached the screenshot of the storyboard so you can get the better understanding. Hope it will help.

[image]